# Parse HTML in Windows Phone 8 without HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, html-parsing

I'm trying to build a app for Windows Phone 8 i'm trying to parse data from a website.HTMLAgilityPack was the right tool for that but when I load my website

```
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);
```

I have this error:

> 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb' does not contain a definition for 'Load' and
>   no extension method 'Load' accepting a first argument of type
>   'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb' was found

**My question is:**
There is an other way like HtmlAgilityPack to parse html in windows phone 8 ?

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't a better question be, "how do I use HtmlAgilityPack"?

Comment: Don't give up on HtmlAgilityPack (or anything) so quickly. Grab the html string and pass it to doc.LoadHtml(htmlString)

Comment: Indeed. Just because something doesn't work for you doesn't mean that it's broken. It's just slightly different on WP.

Comment: @spender - yes, and the doco tab is empty on the codeplex page. So how *do* I learn to use HAP, which I discovered from this question?

Comment: @spender - Never mind. It's available from the downloads tab, despite the documentation tab claiming there isn't any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That method is not available for WP8, since it doesn't allow async downloads. You should somehow download the page and then load it to HtmlDocument, For example

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var html = await client.GetStringAsync("http://stackoverflow.com");

var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is an example from msdn samples: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/HTML-Parser-Code-MSDN-fe21fd6d